# Jupyter Notebook can't hold type string if string is too long

Tags: python, dictionary, jupyter-notebook

I'm working with python and Jupyter Notebook, I've a dictionary in which values are lists with strings in them.

The thing is that the code is giving me an error, I printed the dictionary and everything seems fine, but when I tried to copy and paste it in a cell, I noticed that from a certain point, the strings are no more red but black. So it seems like it don't recognize them as strings anymore.

The strange thing is that if a go to a new line after the last string seen as a proper string (so, displayed in red), the strings that follows are displayed as proper strings.

I manually tried to to this with almost the whole dictionary and with this method the code works.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this strange behaviour (of course I can't do it manually as I did).

example:

```
dict = {'red_key1' : { 'red_key1.1' : ["red_string", "black_string"]}, 'black_key2':  {'black_key2.1' : ["black_string"]}}

dict = {'red_key1' : { 'red_key1.1' : ["red_string",
"red_string"]}, 'red_key2':  {'red_key2.1' : ["black_string"]}}

dict = {'red_key1' : { 'red_key1.1' : ["red_string",
"red_string"]}, 'red_key2':  {'red_key2.1' : 
["red_string"]}}
```

In the example above, the "dict" never changes, I'm just going a capo when I see that the strings are no more displayed in red.

Two screenshot, in the first one you can see the transition from red to black.
In the second one the result after pressing enter (the strings that were black before are now red).

[image]

[image]

If I go to the new line every time black strings start, all the black strings become red and the code works fine until the end. Instead it gives me an error if I keep everything in the original format.

If I run the cell it works fine, but if I try to put the variable in this function:

```
def remove(diz):
    return {k: {inner_key: inner_value for inner_key, inner_value in v.items() if inner_value} for k, v in diz.items() if v}
```

it raises the error 'list' object has no attribute item().

If I manage to go a capo with all the strings the same code works fine.

Thanks!

Comment: could you add a screenshot so we can see what you mention about strings displayed in red?

Comment: Is this a bug in the syntax-highlighting? what happens if you execute such a cell? do you get a syntax error or does it work as expected?

Comment: @jottbe it works fine, and if I print the variable it shows me the dictionary without errors

Comment: Maybe it gets "confused" by the ' in the string? But I would say that is a bug in the syntax highlighting then. Maybe you could check if you can open a bug ticket?!

Comment: but it would make sense to be confused and when I go a capo everything's fine. I'll try to open a bug ticket with jupyter notebook, let's see

Comment: Did you check you are using the same version of Python in both places? Jupyter tends to have a separate environment from the Python installed elsewhere. Could you please edit your post to explain *a capo* in plainer English? You use it twice in your post. Do you just mean "going off the rails"? Or if you 'use pure Python'? You wouldn't be opening a bug with Jupyter unless I am missing something here. The issue would be with the Python or the IPython being used and not Jupyter, I suspect. And none of this is probably attributable to that either. Guessing it is weird characters causing issue.

Comment: sory, the screenshots are useless. In the second screenshot all  strings are red. In the first screenshot we cannot see the whole string. and the strings in the screenshot have nothing to do with the code posted.